# How do I combine these 3 SQL jobs into a single SSIS package?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012, sql-server-data-tools, ssis-2012

I am using `SQL Server 2012`. I currently have 3 jobs running on my database using `T-SQL` queries. I want to group all these 3 SQL jobs into a single `SSIS` package, with each job assigned a specific step in the `SSIS` package.

I will be using `SSDT` to create this package. The `T-SQL` queries for my 3 jobs are as follows:

Job 1:

```
SELECT 
*
INTO dbo.table1
FROM 
   OPENDATASOURCE
   (
      'SQLOLEDB', 
      'Data Source=SourceServer;User ID=MyUser;Password=MyPass'
   ).SourceDatabase.dbo.SourceTable;
```

Jobs 2 and 3 are the same as above, except for the table names being imported.

Do I need to have 3 separate SSIS packages for each job and then merge these 3 SSIS packages into a single final SSIS package? Also, which task should I use to achieve this?

Comment: First consider your reasons for migrating this to an SSIS package. Note that now you need to use another tool to maintain it - SSDT, and this tool can have issues installing and coexisting with visual studio.

Comment: I am a bit confused regarding your comment about installation and co-existence issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have all of these in a single package like this:

[image]

*I have just one note* - what if, say, `Job 2` task will fail? Should the entire transaction rollback? If so - you should consider using the [DataFlow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/data-flow) task preceded by `BEGIN TRANSACTION` and followed by `COMMIT TRANSACTION` as described in [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3072/sql-server-integration-services-ssis-transactions-without-msdtc/) article. You can also use `Failure` task to report possible issues.

Also, one more thing - you don't need SSIS package here. What about creating a `stored procedure` and just calling this proc from a simple `T-SQL Job` similarly as you already do now? You could take care of transaction stuff on one place. Just a thought.

Comment: Thanks Ivan! I will give this a try. Can you elaborate regarding the stored procedure? Any online example I can refer to?

Comment: @user3115933 Sure, you're welcome. This is how you can create a stored procedure: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/create-a-stored-procedure and here is an example how to run it under SQL Agent: https://www.mindstick.com/blog/11027/create-sql-server-agent-job-to-run-stored-procedure

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to split your Jobs into separate packages, it will not be beneficial in your case. From maintenance reason I would use single package.
Simply put your T-SQL command text in **Execute SQL Task** - [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/execute-sql-task) is Microsoft Docs description

SSIS can offer exception handling. Say, if *Step 2* fails then *Step 1* changes should be rolled back. This can be achieved if you put all three steps in a sequence and set its *TransactionSupport* property to *Required*. This is just an example.